# return flag value with sysrefcursor like Oracle

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

```
PROCEDURE TEST
(
    I_EMP_NAME              IN EMP.EMP_NAME%TYPE,
    I_EMP_ID                IN EMP.EMP_ID %TYPE,
    O_SET                   OUT SRESULTSET,
    O_FLAG                  OUT NUMBER
)
IS
BEGIN
    UPDATE
        EMP
    SET
        EMP_NAME = I_EMP_NAME,
        LAST_DATE = SYSDATE,
        DEPTNO = 30  
    WHERE
        EMP_ID = I_EMP_ID;
    IF SQL%ROWCOUNT = 0 THEN
            O_FLAG := 1;
        ELSE
            O_FLAG := 0;
        END IF;
    OPEN O_SET FOR
    SELECT
        EMP_ID,
        EMP_JOINING_DATE,
        EMP_LAST_DATE,
        EMP_SAL
    FROM
       EMP 
    WHERE
       EMP_NAME = I_EMP_NAME AND EMP_ID = I_EMP_ID;
END TEST;
```

Can anyone suggest to me how I can return both the output in PostgreSQL like Oracle (above code is in Oracle).

Here I can use `returns table` for `sResultSet` (it is a sysrefcursor), but I am not able to return flag value in PostgreSQL.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test(i_emp_name text, i_emp_ID double precision)
RETURNS TABLE(
    emp_ID numeric,
    emp_joining_date timestamp without time zone,
    emp_last_date timestamp without time zone,
    emp_sal double precision
) LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$ ...
```

Comment: That will cause an error in Oracle as `I_ID` is undefined. What keeps you from returning an additional column in the result table in PostgreSQL?

Comment: Sorry that was I_emp_ID not I_ID

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification. Now, what's the problem with returning an extra column?

Comment: Try `RETURNS RECORD` with multiple `OUT` parameters...

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe actually in oracle i can return both sysrefcursor and another flag value as out parameter but in this scenario how can i do in postgresql.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Thanks for your response.

Comment: If you want to return a `refcursor` and a different value, you can define the function to `RETURNS TABLE (sresultset refcursor, flag boolean)` and return just a single row. You should hint the optimizer with `ROWS 1`.

Answer (score 0):

Postgresql has supported `OUT` parameters since at least version 8.1. In pgplsql an OUT parameter is specified slightly differently than it is in PL/SQL - you put the `OUT` **before** the name of the parameter instead of after it. So your procedure should be defined as

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test(IN i_emp_name text,
                                IN i_emp_ID numeric,
                                OUT o_flag numeric,
                                OUT emp_joining_date timestamp without time zone,
                                OUT emp_last_date timestamp without time zone,
                                OUT emp_sal double precision
) LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$ ...
```

Note that functions with output parameters are treated as returning a record, so defining a record to return is not needed. Also note that no other return type is defined because the implicit record of `OUT` parameters becomes the return type. You could invoke the above as

```
SELECT test('Bob', '1').emp_sal;
```

and it should display Bob's salary. Or you could do

```
select * from test('Bob', '1');
```

and it should display something like

```
o_flag    emp_joining_date      emp_last_date     emp_sal
1         11-Jan-2016           28-Nov-2017       1000000.00
```

See [this slightly confusing journal post](http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/129-Use-of-OUT-and-INOUT-Parameters.html), [this somewhat better tutorial](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/plpgsql-function-parameters/), and [of course there's always the documentation (see 'argmode')](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-createfunction.html).